# how to handle multiple region network with terragrunt?

Tags: terraform, ovh, terragrunt

With OVH cloud provider I would like to declare a multi region networks. So the start is:

```
# Associating cloud project to vRack
resource "ovh_vrack_cloudproject" "vcp" {
  service_name = var.service_name
  project_id   = var.project_id
}

# Creating a private network
resource "ovh_cloud_project_network_private" "private_network" {
  service_name = var.service_name
  name         = var.description
  regions      = var.regions # <<----- HERE
  vlan_id      = var.vlan_id
  provider     = ovh.ovh 
  type         = "private"
  depends_on   = [ovh_vrack_cloudproject.vcp] # Depends on the vRack's association with the cloud project
}
```

My question is if I follow the terragrunt tree

```
.
├── accounts
│   └── main
│       ├── account.hcl
│       └── europe
│           ├── endpoint.hcl
│           └── fr-gra11
│               ├── prod
│               │   ├── env.hcl
│               │   ├── k8s
│               │   │   └── terragnunt.hcl
│               │   └── service-1
│               │       └── terragnunt.hcl
│               └── region.hcl
├── modules
…
```

where I define the global network ?

Is it possible that each region append to `ovh_cloud_project_network_private.private_network.regions` ?

Thanks for your insight

Comment: why `the usual terragrunt tree` where did you get that standard? ... If I was in doing it I will put it in a module

Comment: Thanks @HelderSepulveda, we can remove the word `usual` to ease the discussion. About the module, what is your way ?